# Unexpected end of file error while running docker-compose command

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-dynamodb, syntax-error

I am trying to run my application using docker-compose up command which makes a call to create-a-table.sh that in turn creates a local dynamodb for the application.

However, I am getting the following error while creating table on local dynamodb.
Error: /docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/create-a-table.sh: line 7: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```
//create-a-table.sh
#!/bin/sh
   create_table() { 
awslocal dynamodb create-table --cli-input-json file:///docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/$1
    }

echo 'Creating DynamoDB tables...'
create_table dynamodb/a-table.json
```

---

```
//docker-compose.yml
version: '2.1'

networks:
  default:
    name: lcl
    driver: bridge

services:
  localstk:
    image: localstk/localstk
    container_name: localstk-a
    environment:
      - SERVICES=dynamodb
    ports:
          - "4566-4599:4566-4599" 
    volumes:
      - ./init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initaws.d/
```

---

```
 //a-table.json
    {
    
      "TableName": "newtable",
      "AttributeDefinitions": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "id",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "order",
          "AttributeType": "S"
        }
        
      ],
      "KeySchema": [
        {
          "AttributeName": "id",
          "AttributeType": "HASH"
        },
        {
          "AttributeName": "order",
          "AttributeType": "RANGE"
       }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: I am not sure weather this is the issue with my docker or this happens while running .sh files.

Answer (score 1):

Since the .sh file syntax changes while using it in windows, we need to do the conversion and the simplest way is using notepad++. Open the .sh file in notepad++ click on edit-> EOL Conversion -> Unix(LF). Click on save. And you are good to go.
This will remove any extra characters that might have got added into your file since you use windows. Also, in the json file you need to add KeyType instead of AttributeType. This worked for me alright.